# In JSONATA, how to fetch values from object using variable

Tags: jsonata

$test := 'Account Name';

I need to know how can I use the variable as a key.
These are not working:

1. $.$test
2. $.[$test]
3. $[$test]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$lookup function](https://docs.jsonata.org/object-functions#lookup) to access a dynamically defined key:

```
$lookup($, $test)
```

See it on the playground: https://stedi.link/TYRXYoy

Comment: Hi, do you know any alternative to $lookup? I am having problems with this function

Comment: could you describe your problem? an example could help

Comment: I posted the issue in their Github, thank you!